# Hoare's Partition Scheme Stuck

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I'm tracing through a quick sort algorithm on paper, but I keep getting stuck on the partitioning using Hoare's partitioning.  The array is `{3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5}`.  I'm using median of three for the pivot, so pivot is 5, I swap the pivot with the left and have `{5,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,3}`.  I go through the algorithm as follows

1. Swap A[4] with A[10]: A= `{5,1,4,1,3,9,2,6,5,3,5}`
2. Swap A[5] with A[10]: A= `{5,1,4,1,3,5,2,6,5,3,9}`
3. Swap A[5] with A[9]: A= `{5,1,4,1,3,3,2,6,5,5,9}`
4. Swap A[7] with A[9]: A= `{5,1,4,1,3,3,2,5,5,6,9}`

So I have the pointers stuck on the the two 5's at A[7] and A[8], but Hoare's keeps telling me to flip those two because i < j so I have to keep flipping.  I know there's something I'm doing wrong, but I don't understand what it is.

Comment: This is basically debugging pseudocode for a specific version of quicksort. We cannot really help you unless you tell us your pseudocode. There might be a small error in the pseudocode, or perhaps you're misunderstanding something. Try to understand what the algorithm is trying to do, and correct it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Since your pivot value is 5, the comparison with A[7] and A[8], which are both 5, will be `=pval`.

While you didn't share the pseudocode you used, I believe you used a while loop for incrementing/decrementing the pointers. This means the pointers will just be stuck at A[7] and A[8] as they do not satisfy the expressions `<pval` or `>pval`.

Instead of using a while loop, you should pre-decrement the left pointer and pre-increment the right pointer, then use a do-while loop. This will ensure that the pointers will increment/decrement at least once even if it is `=pval`.

This website has an implementation of both Hoare's and Lomuto schemes.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hoares-vs-lomuto-partition-scheme-quicksort/

Comment: Wow, very good observation. While implementing a quicksort I got rid of this `do-while` in preference of `for` because I thought it's just a micro-optimization to do one less comparison each cycle, but then that requires you to pass out of boundaries indices or pointers, which is kinda annoying. Turns out it's a guard against a case where all elements are the same.